# how to add icons in vs code itself

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

[image]

in the picture next to column.isSortedDesc , "Down" and "up" arrows are typed in code itself in vscode editor how can we add icons like this in code it self

Comment: in CSS with `::before` and `::after`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are not icons but plain emojies, vscode has support for UNICODE emoji characters by default, you could just copy and paste emojies into code just like you do with text. Here is a full list of emojies for reference that you could use in your code: https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is a couple of years old, but I love the following shortcuts.

As Dev Sebastian stated, they are not icons and instead are emojis. One can either use the UNICODE value, copy and paste from somewhere else, or use your operating system keyboard shortcut.

when editing text:

[windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-keyboard-tips-and-tricks-588e0b72-0fff-6d3f-aeee-6e5116097942#:%7E:text=During%20text%20entry,one%20you%20like.): Windows logo key  + . (period)

[mac](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/mchlp1560/mac#:%7E:text=In%20an%20app,in%20Keyboard%20settings.) : command + control + space